# In Typescript, how to define a type with exact number of property of unknown names

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a variable. It has a name and a value, and I want them both for something, e.g. to log them - the value **and a variable name**. It can be done like so:

```js
const some_symbol = "qwer"
const some_other_symbol = 100000

const log1 = (name: string, value: any) => console.log(name, value)

log1("some_symbol", some_symbol)
log1("some_other_symbol", some_other_symbol)
log1("some_symbol", some_symbol, "some_other_symbol", some_other_symbol) // compile time error
log1() // compile time error
```

But a much better way would be

```js
log2({some_symbol})
log2({some_other_symbol})
```

To do so I can write a function

```js
const log2 = (obj: { [key: string]: any }) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj)
    if( keys.length !== 1 ) throw new Error("only one key is expected")
    const key = keys[0]
    console.log(key, obj[key])
}
```

But

```js
log2({some_symbol, some_other_symbol}) // compiles. run time error
log2({}) // compiles. run time error
```

I want **compilation to fail** on lines like `log2({v1, v2})` and `log2({})`.
I would like get rid of dynamic type checks, and enforce a compile time check that `obj` param has only one key. And in general case - exact number of keys which names are unknown to me.

Comment: I think you're looking at this from the wrong angle. You shouldn't need a specific variable to be logged. Or rather, this is *very* low level logging that is super specific and is unlikely to be generally useful. It's better to include logs that make sense when read without necessarily having access to the source code. Saying `"variably {x} is {y}"` requires knowledge of both 1. exactly where from the source code is that coming from 2. ability to understand the source code in order to work out what's happening. Something you are better off using a debugger for.

Comment: @VLAZ, thanks, but actually, my use case is about code generation. Logging is just a simplified example.

Comment: You would have to repeat the variable name as generic type argument like [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiA5gJhgXhgHgNIwKYAeUeYAJhDAAoBOIADntVAJ7Z7MB8AFCAEYBWALhgBvGAG1KMAJZgY2ALrCAhmGYwAvgEp0HUQCgYRmKEiwA1uwoYA8gLzAoAOkvMIPATuUVs4hYeNpADMYLlcIJzgSRCgACxgAQjQMAEYdONoAdxgwPGyAUWpaai4AInA4dXA8GFcZCkIGRzxSUq0Ao1NoWvZ0HrdxAAZ-YxNwCBAoyKQw9gAaGD5+cVcFdo19fS7YCYBbPAB9CGZd3km+0oBHTMZSrfGdkH2DkDjGI5OzuD6Uwb+-zYIFCYUp7Q7HU6TUrcMRgj6QuALOGvWLvCFfTQ6AD0WLGuzo0iiERg1AArnIoNJ9vgiiBqPogcgQXD0VCYdoYDi8QSiU4SeSYJTqYxikA).

Comment: @ford04, thanks, that's better than `log1()`. It would protect me from errors like `log1("some_symbol", some_other_symbol)`. I even thought to ask you to post it as an answer... but it is not as good as `log2()`, and it's not really an answer to the question in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sufficient type system juggling you can get the compiler to complain if your object has more than one known key. Something like this might work:

```
type OneKey<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never :
    K extends any ? { [P in keyof T]?: P extends K ? T[P] : never } : never;    

function log2<T extends object & OneKey<T>>(obj: T): void;
function log2(obj: any) {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj)
    if (keys.length !== 1) throw new Error("only one key is expected")
    const key = keys[0]
    console.log(key, obj[key])
}
```

We're limiting `T` to object types without index signatures (because you can't be sure an index-signature object has only one key), and then we are making sure that the object is assignable to a "one-key" version of itself.  If the object you pass is type `{a: string, b: number}` then it checks against the union `{a?: string, b?: undefined} | {a?: undefined, b?: number}`.  Meaning it checks "either an `a` and no `b`, or a `b` and no `a`".  That doesn't match, so it fails.  If you pass type `{a: string}`, then the checked type is `{a?: string}`, which does match.

Let's make sure it works:

```
log2({ some_symbol }); // okay
log2({ some_symbol, some_other_symbol }); // error
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '{ some_symbol: string; some_other_symbol: number; }' is not assignable 
// to type '{ some_symbol?: undefined; some_other_symbol?: number | undefined; }'.
log2({}); // error
//   ~~
// Type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Looks good to me.

Note that there are probably all sorts of edge cases. The type system isn't geared toward enforcing this type of check.  I'd expect if you pass an object with optional keys, or which is itself a union, you might see weird behavior.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdhA0hEAeAKgGioqEAewEcAJgM5QDWKA9gGZTpQC8VtD6AfCwLABQUQVDLAATgEs4AczyFi5HFAD8UBADcIoqAC5VAVwC2AI02yipCrhXrT2-kMUFzCgIZwQyqAG8oAbQAKUJJsIPSMALpKuoFO8pae6AHhOqoQGloAvik2ogDc-Pb8dHpwAMbA4jRwUAA2NFIATBhmcVA0RgBWEOVQAGSwCMhoXJwAFO0duugAlLpqNOIk+XzFZRVVtfUN4526biDT3vZCpVUiIRSsMJ3dwAB01CBkOx3Tx4LiDKOPZHc1xFJgAALKAAQmYrAAjIdgaIaAB3VKIgCiojholGACIqjUPFVoI8ghQCJByhASJi3gITmdgCEWBdfAAGcLvKCnOBkGj-P71b4obATXyPcJUjIFPgc85cgwQAD6ZBAxm5DMxAEd4ZpMfwpXSZfKaMDNAqlUYVVCmZbLRLdZspJCGaM4C5ZboRBJpNg1C4anoIHt3IdmNwpdyILypE6XRAvT6-VT+HVGqMfPqTcqalAMtNclAAPR5tqUFwgRNbFPCGiy9NmmrYNOGoHGxUZrM5-OFzTo-gFoQAPwHg6Hw5Ho5HPcL6HA0AA5Kmq-KW7W3WJJFJcw2jaIa9zdHBDCY8lmZ0TVIaoC4yGRxFJnUZ-lAJ1BgDRn9OoHPK9Wl9yolASiQEB0JI5IbgucqNs2pq-nuB6mAAPv+pBASBSzHncZbJl42a5r2XY0KIT6CAOT5TpAH7YSe4gUHA56Xtet4uPe0AvlAYAuKI0ZEFoYSgORM45DOdxAA)

Comment: thanks. Voted up. I'll spend some time contemplating it, and if there would be no solution for an arbitrary number of keys I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
const log2 = (obj: { [key: string]: any }) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj)
    // in your two run time examples. you have 2 keys, and 0 keys, and thus
    // by design your code throws an error
    if( keys.length !== 1 ) throw new Error("only one key is expected")
    const key = keys[0]
    console.log(key, obj[key])
}
```

I'm not sure what you're expecting. It compiles because it's correct. It gives you a runtime error because of your code.

Perhaps, you meant to call your function as:

```
log2({some_symbol: some_other_symbol})
```

This makes it a dictionary with only a single key, which will pass your code check.

Comment: Yes it compiles because it's correct. But I want exactly opposite - I want compilation to fail on `log2({v1, v2})` and `log2({})`. Updated the question to clarify.